# Dockerfile directory structure for Go Webapp

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, dockerfile, go-html-template

I'm developing a test hello app in Go, which will have access to a Postgres DB. This will use a statefulset to release in kubernetes and has one pod with two container images (one for pgsql & one for goapp).

```
├── hello-app
|   ├── templates
|       ├── file1.gohtml
|       ├── file2.gohtml
|       └── file3.gohtml
|   ├── Dockerfile
|   └── hello-app.go
├── psql
|   ├── Dockerfile
|   ├── createUser.sh
|   └── createDB.sql
├── yaml
|   └── statefulset.yaml
```

I am stuck getting the Dockerfile and Go app to tie up. In my first bit of Go code I use the 'template.Must' function to reference the 'templates' directory. Obviously when I run this up as a container the directory structure is different.

I've not quite worked out how to do this in the Dockerfile yet and was looking for some guidance.

**/app/hello-app.go**

```
package main

import (

        "database/sql"
        "fmt"
        "os"
        _ "github.com/lib/pq"
        "html/template"
        "net/http"
        "strconv"
)

var db *sql.DB
var tpl *template.Template

func init() {
        host := os.Getenv("VARIABLE")
        var err error
        db, err = sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://user:password@"+host+"/dbname?sslmode=disable")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("You connected to your database.")

        tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml"))
```

**/app/Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:1.8-alpine
RUN apk add --update go git
RUN go get github.com/lib/pq/...
ADD . /go/src/hello-app
RUN go install hello-app
Add templates templates/
ENV USER=username \
    PASSWORD=password \
    DB=dbname \
    HOST=hostname \
    PORT=5432

FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=0 /go/bin/hello-app/ .
ENV PORT 4040
CMD ["./hello-app"]
```

When I run this up as is in kubernetes (GCP) I get the following log entry on the hello-app container.

> panic: html/template: pattern matches no files: `templates/*.gohtml`
>   goroutine 1 [running]: html/template.Must

Comment: That `ENV` instruction isn't useful in the Dockerfile shown, as it's scoped to a build stage, which ends immediately after it (and a new one starts). Also, keep in mind that if you had that `ENV` instruction in the last stage (i.e., the actual image that is being build), it could be a security problem, as you'd be persisting in the image — and in every system that stores that image — the credentials to a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second stage of your Dockerfile, you are only copying your Go binary from the previous stage. You must also copy your `templates` directory to the second stage as well so the Go binary can reference your HTML templates:

```
FROM golang:1.8-alpine
RUN apk add --update go git
RUN go get github.com/lib/pq/...
ADD . /go/src/hello-app
RUN go install hello-app
ENV USER=username \
    PASSWORD=password \
    DB=dbname \
    HOST=hostname \
    PORT=5432

FROM alpine:latest
COPY --from=0 /go/bin/hello-app/ .
COPY --from=0 /go/src/hello-app/templates ./templates
ENV PORT 4040
CMD ["./hello-app"]
```

I'm not sure if this is common practice but when I'm confused about what contents are in what folder within the build process, I simply `ls` the directory in question to get a better understanding of what might be happening during the build process:

```
RUN ls
```

Obviously you can remove these lines once you've finalized your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

That error is because, the `template.ParseGlob` cannot find any matching files in your templates directory. Instead of `COPY --from=0 /go/bin/hello-app/ .` try copying the entire directory using `COPY <YOUR LOCAL GOPATH/src/hello-app> <DOCKER DIR PATH>`. Also when you build the app, your templates folder will still be in source folder, so that too might be causing the problem. Solution is to run a `go build`in the app directory and use the the `COPY` command I have.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error with my templates' folder but solved it by copying all the files from my root folder using this command in my Dockerfile:

```
COPY . .
```

In addition, when you are using an external library you might want to enable the GO111MODULE.

In your Terminal (MacOS):

```
export GO111MODULE=on
go mod init
```

In your Dockerfile:

```
COPY go.mod .
RUN go mod download
```